# Candy Crush Jelly Fish

Tags: candy-crush-saga

When the jelly fish appears in the game what are you supposed to 
tap to get the extra points? Do you tap the fish swimming by? Or do you tap the colored candy?

Comment: You don't tap anything, you unlock the fish by making a combo, just like everything else in the game.

Answer (score 2):

Jellyfish candy will just randomly pick a candy on the board and break it, causing other candies to fall to replace them.

There's nothing to tap when they're doing this, it's completely automatic.